# How to convert specific algorithm with streams

Tags: java, java-stream

The task is to return `String` with sum of every letter. The input is also a `String`.

For example

```
input: dasamdw
output: s1d2a2m1w1
```

I came out with a simple quick algorithm:

```
private String method(String input) {
    Map<String, Integer> integerMap = new HashMap<>();
    for( char c : input.toCharArray()) {
        String key = String.valueOf(c);
        if(integerMap.containsKey(key)) {
            integerMap.put(key, integerMap.get(key) + 1);
        } else {
            integerMap.put(key, 1);
        }
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : integerMap.entrySet()) {
        sb.append(e.getKey());
        sb.append(e.getValue());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

But I really would like to use streams for that, someting like:

```
private String method(String input) {
    Map<Character, Integer> collect =
        input.chars().
        mapToObj(i -> (char)i).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting() ));

    return collect.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + "" + entry.getValue())
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

But I can't figure out the right `groupingBy` part...

Comment: note that your program should output `a2s1d2w1m1` rather than `s1d2a2m1w1` but I guess the order doesn't matter in this case anyway.

Comment: @Aominè: there is no guaranteed output order for `HashMap`.

Comment: @Holger thanks again, I seem to forget this fact every now and then probably because of my lack of involvement with Map API. maybe I should take some time to have a read at the docs ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that even your loop version can be simplified

```
private String method(String input) {
    Map<Character, Integer> integerMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(char c: input.toCharArray()) {
        integerMap.merge(c, 1, Integer::sum);
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(Map.Entry<Character, Integer> e : integerMap.entrySet()) {
        sb.append(e.getKey()).append(e.getValue());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and it’s not the worst imaginable solution. Using Java 8 doesn’t imply converting everything to Stream API use.

You can use a Stream solution like this.

```
private String method(String input) {
    return input.chars().boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> Character.toString((char)e.getKey().intValue())+e.getValue())
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

But note that the simplest solution is not always the most efficient solution, e.g. the following solution might be preferable for large strings:

```
private String method(String input) {
    IntSummaryStatistics ss = input.chars().summaryStatistics();
    int min = ss.getMin();
    int[] counts = new int[ss.getMax()-min+1];
    input.chars().forEach(c -> counts[c-min]++);
    return IntStream.range(0, counts.length)
        .filter(ix -> counts[ix] > 0)
        .collect(StringBuilder::new,
                 (sb,c)->sb.append((char)(c+min)).append(counts[c]),
                 StringBuilder::append)
        .toString();
}
```

Besides avoiding overhead compared to the other solutions, it also returns an intrinsically sorted result.

Another alternative producing a sorted result would be

```
private String method(String input) {
    char[] array = input.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(array);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int ix = 0, e; ix<array.length; ix = e) {
        char c = array[ix];
        for(e = ix+1; e<array.length && array[e]==c; ) e++;
        sb.append(c).append(e-ix);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as [*Collectors.counting()*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--) returns *Long*, you'll need to change the map target type from:

```
Map<Character, Integer> collect
```

to

```
Map<Character, Long> collect
```

---

That aside, you can combine your `groupingBy` and `joining` 
 collectors by using `Collectors.collectingAndThen` i.e:

```
return Arrays.stream(input.split(""))
             .collect(
                 collectingAndThen(groupingBy(identity(), counting()), 
                         e -> e.entrySet()
                               .stream()
                               .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + entry.getValue())
                               .collect(joining())));
```

make sure to use the imports:

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.*;
import static java.util.function.Function.*;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String foo = "dasamdw";
Arrays.stream(foo.split(""))
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
          .entrySet().stream()
                     .map(entry -> entry.getKey() + entry.getValue())
                     .collect(Collectors.joining(""));
```

This gives the result -> a2s1d2w1m1

You can add your sorting how you would need however you needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version, I added some comments so you can get by easier:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        // your given string
        String x = "dasamdw";
        // map to store each letter:numberOfRepetition pairs (I used   TreeMap just to print letters alphabetically)
        Map<String, Integer> letters = new TreeMap<>();

        // stream of char[] from the given string, add letter to the map if it doesnt exist with value 1
        // if it already exists, just increase value by 1
        Arrays.stream(x.split("")).forEach(y -> letters.put(y, letters.get(y) == null ? 1 : letters.get(y) + 1));

        // loop over map and print out the results of lambda above
        for (Map.Entry s : letters.entrySet()) {
            System.out.print(s.getKey() + "" + s.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

You can also replace ternary with [Merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-)

Comment: there's also `letters.merge(y, 1, (oldV, newV) -> oldV+newV)`